# Poor quality of x-ray in 2.8

Tags: artifacts

Who knows what's the reason of such poor shading in x-ray mode?
[image]
I can't do sculpting because i simply cannot see the shape because of these artifacts
X-ray value - 0.877

Viewport settings
[image]